# Geometry- finding the measure of the angle

Tags: geometry

Here's my question:
Mathilde and Mathieu are trying to make two cones  from a paper disk of 20 cm of diameter. Mathilde is making her cone with a paper sector with an angle α and Mathieu made ​​his With the Rest of the disk. They notice that Mathilde's cone is 2 times higher than Mathieu's .
What is the measure of the angle α ?

Comment: To make sure I understand.  The disk was cut into two sectors each which was made into a cone?

Comment: Yes !! each sector was made into a cone!

Comment: So the question is how does the sector angle relate to height.  Obviously the larger sector angle result in shorter cones but how?  A cone is described by three variables.  radius (of base) and height and side.  Mathildes base has a circumference of $\alpha/360*C$ whereas Mathieu has a circumference of $(360 - \alpha)/360 * C$ so the radius can be calculated.  height = square root (side^2 - radius^2) so we can solve this.

Comment: Times As High As, not Times Higher Than. ...Times More Than was started by innumerate journalists who couldn't distinguish between a propotionate increase and a ratio.

Comment: @user254665 that's a very reasonable pet peeve.  But I think as "times more than" doesn't make any literal sense ("5 times *what* more than?") I can accept "times more than" = "times as" as a colloquialism.

Comment: ...unless "times more than" means "more than by n times its height".  In which case "n times more than" means "n + 1 times as".  *sigh*  I think this is something we'll just have to live with.

Answer (score 2):

Okay bear with me.

The circumference of the Circle is $20 \pi$.

Mathilda takes $\alpha/360$ of that circumference so her base of her cane will have a circumference of $\alpha/360*20\pi= \alpha/18 *\pi$.  So the radius of the base of her cone will $\alpha/36$.

Mathieu takes $(360 - \alpha)/360$ of the circumference so his base radius will by $(360-\alpha)/36$.

Both the cones will have a side of 10 cm (half the original circle's diameter).

Now radius and height form a right triangle with side as the hypotenuse.

So  Mathieu's height is $\sqrt{10^2 - \frac{360 - \alpha}{36}^2}$

Mathilda's height is $\sqrt{10^2 - \frac{\alpha}{36}^2}$

So $2 = \dfrac{\sqrt{10^2 - \frac{\alpha}{36}^2}}{\sqrt{10^2 - \frac{360 - \alpha}{36}^2}}$

Solve for $\alpha$.

So $4 = \dfrac{10^2 - \frac{\alpha}{36}^2}{{10^2 - \frac{360 - \alpha}{36}^2}}$

$400 - 4*\frac{360- \alpha}{36}^2 = 100 -\frac{\alpha}{36}^2$

$4*\frac{360- \alpha}{36}^2 -\frac{\alpha}{36}^2 = 300$

$4(360^2 - 720\alpha + \alpha^2) - \alpha^2 = 300*36^2$

$4*360^2 - 4*720\alpha + 3\alpha^2 = 300*36^2$

$\alpha^2 - 4*240\alpha  =  100*36^2 - 4*120*360$

$\alpha^2 - 4*240\alpha + 480^2 =  100*36^2 - 4*120*360 + 480^2$

$(\alpha - 480)^2 =  100*36^2 - 4*120*360 + 480^2$

$\alpha - 480 = \pm\sqrt{100*36^2 - 4*120*360 + 480^2}$

$= \pm4\sqrt{100*9^2 - 120*90 + 120^2}= \pm40\sqrt{9^2 - 12*9 + 12^2}$

$=\pm40\sqrt{9(9-12) + 144} = \pm40\sqrt{117} = 432.66$

$\alpha = 480 \pm 432.66$

$\alpha = 47.33$

Unless I made an arithmetical error.